# Using a _ but not as a wildcard search, its part of the string im looking for

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a string value that contains values and end for example as follows `123456_NS`. But also in the column are a lot of other values aswell.
My problem here is I want to extract from this string column all the values that end in `_NS` but using `LIKE %_NS` don't return the desired result, as it also return values for me e.g. Waltons

Any idea how to get around that sql don't see my `_` as a wildcard but part of the string im searching for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the wildcard character `_` in brackets:

```
LIKE '%[_]NS d'
```

otherwise `_`(underscore) means  *any single character*.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx